# CoordinatorLayout with ViewPager2 and NestedScrollView is different then expected

Tags: android, xml, android-coordinatorlayout, android-viewpager2, android-nestedscrollview

When I built a layout with a coordinator layout, I have used the view pager2. The design blueprint is right while the result is wrong. The height of view pager is wrong, could you tell me where I am wrong?

```
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
                android:id="@+id/main_scroll"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="@color/white">
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:toolbarId="@+id/title_toolbar"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/title_toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarPopupTheme"
                        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingTextAppearance"/>
                <include android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                         layout="@layout/header_tool_bar"
                         app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"></include>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/view_pager_2"></androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Add your screenshots actual and expected... might be helpful

Comment: app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" <- This line of code add additional space on the bottom of the screen, so it`s expected behavior.

Comment: Hi bro, any luck for this one ?